# Sponsored tag images not displaying

Tags: support, tags, images, sponsored-tags

Is it normal that I'm having this display and how can I fix it?

> [image]

Comment: You (or your ISP/Network Administrators) seem to have blocked access to i.stack.imgur.com (likely a sweeping ban on *.imgur.com). You need to get access to i.stack.imgur.com in order to see these images. Talk to your ISP/Network Administrators.

Comment: Yes, ithink it's that  the problème thank you

Comment: Maby you can write this as an answer so that i can checked like answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on your network (or your ISP/Network Administrators) seems to have blocked access to `i.stack.imgur.com`, which is where these images are hosted (this is a private instance of imgur that is for Stack Exchange usage only).

What likely happened is there is a sweeping ban on `*.imgur.com`. You need to get access to `i.stack.imgur.com` in order to see these images.

Talk to your ISP/Network Administrators to enable access.

It is also possible that a browser extension has blocked this access - you would need to relax the rules similarly to above.